# How do i automatically download the files from submitting a form on a website

Tags: forms, post, automation

overall i want to download all the item specifics for a list of ebay categories.
if you know any other solutions please let me know.

i want to download ebay item specifics, the below website i found works but only for one at a time. i need help automating that.

the website url is http://dtstools.ebaystratus.com/ItemSpecificLookup_WebApp/index.aspx/index

and a list of example second values are:
1059
57990
57991
15687
137084
3002
57988
11483
57989
15689
11510
11511
3001
11484
155183
15690
11507
15691
84434
313

the list i have is very long, approximately 10,000.
as long as all the files download in a folder ill be happy :)

thanks

Comment: What language do you want to use?  If you post the code you've tried already, you'll get better responses.

Comment: php preferablly, ive tried loads of things. Im not too fussed what the method would be as long as i end up with the files.